# Registering Dependency with in NServiceBus with Autofac after upgrade

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, nservicebus

I am having a problem working out how to register dependencies in my NServiceBus endpoint.  I am using NServiceBus 7.2 and Autofac 5.0 and NServiceBus.Autofac 7.0.0 and can't find any examples that use these versions.  I am using Asp.Net Core 3.

My Program.cs code looks like this

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

My ConfigureServices method looks like this

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.InstallServicesInAssembly(Configuration);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).Assembly);

        }
```

This runs all the installers I have but this runs BEFORE the ConfigureContainer method called by the Framework.  AutoFac automatically adds all the services that have been added in COnfigureServices.  I have a separate class for each installer.  My ConfigureContainer method is currently empty since the Automapper and MediatR services are added anyway because the services are added in ConfigureServices.  This resolves both IMediatR and IMapper when they are injected into the controllers of the Api.  But they are not available in the NServiceBus Message Handlers.  This is because I can't see how to register the endpoint configuration or share the Autofac container after it is created.  See the NServiceBus installer code comment below.

```
 //here we register stuff directly with autofac
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Register your own things directly with Autofac, like:

        //builder.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
       // builder.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
    }
```

I want to be able to make use of AutoMapper and MediatR in my NServiceBus Message Handlers and so want these dependencies injected into the constructors of the handlers.

And My NServiceBusInstaller is as follows

```
public class NServiceBusInstaller : IInstaller
{
    public async void InstallServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var rabbitMQSettings = new RabbitMQSettings();
        configuration.Bind(nameof(rabbitMQSettings), rabbitMQSettings);
        services.AddSingleton(rabbitMQSettings);

        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(rabbitMQSettings.SilvaDirectory);
        endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

        //Here I want to configure the endpoint to use the dependencies in the AutoFac container
        //How to get reference to this container??

        /*
        endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(
           customizations: customizations => {
               customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(container);
           });
        */

        var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();
        transport.UseConventionalRoutingTopology();
        transport.ConnectionString(rabbitMQSettings.ConnectionString);
        transport.TimeToWaitBeforeTriggeringCircuitBreaker(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));


        //services.AddNServiceBus(endpointConfiguration);

        await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).ConfigureAwait(false);


    }
}
```

ANd finally one of my message handlers looks like this.  Currently I am getting an Exception because NServiceBus cannot resolve the IMapper and IMediator..

```
public class CreateDirectoryEntryHandler : IHandleMessages<CreateDirectoryEntry>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    public CreateDirectoryEntryHandler(IMapper mapper, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }
    public async Task Handle(CreateDirectoryEntry message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {

        var command = _mapper.Map<CreateNewCustomerCommand>(message);
        CommandResponse response = await _mediator.Send(command);

        if(response.Success)
        {
            await context.Reply(new DirectoryEntryCreated() { Email = message.Email }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Reply(new DirectoryEntryRejected() { Email = message.Email, Error = response.Error }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

    }
}
```

I am probably missing something obvious.  My mental block is because the ConfigureContainer method is called after the Configure services method by the framework so I don't have the container reference to pass in to the NServiceBus installer. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at this sample https://docs.particular.net/samples/dependency-injection/aspnetcore/. It shows how to use Asp.Net Core 3 with NServiceBus and Autofac.

In your sample code, you use `endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>()` API that assumes it's NServiceBus that controls the lifecycle of the DI container. This obviously isn't the case.

The sample uses [NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting/) and [Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting/) packages. First, makes sure that NServiceBus can work with DI container that is managed externally by via [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting) and the second is Autofac adapter for Microsoft DI abstractions.